# Inserting Dataset + additional columns into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dataset

This seems like a pretty straightforward problem but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I have a dataset [a combination of some UNION's] that needs to be inserted into a table.

Dataset:

```
SELECT COL1 AS A, COL2 AS B, COL3 AS C
UNION ALL
SELECT COL1 AS A, COL2 AS B, COL3 AS C
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1
A varchar(50),
B varchar(50),
C varchar(50),
USERID varchar(50),
TIMESTAMP timestamp
```

I'm trying:

```
    INSERT INTO TBL1
--syntax error here
    (SELECT COL1 AS A, COL2 AS B, COL3 AS C
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COL1 AS A, COL2 AS B, COL3 AS C)
--syntax error here
    ,'USER'
    ,GETDATE()
```

I get syntax errors on the line where the select starts and where it ends [comments]

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna want to make your union a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO TBL1
SELECT A, B, C, 'USER', GETDATE()
FROM
(
    SELECT COL1 AS A, COL2 AS B, COL3 AS C
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COL1 AS A, COL2 AS B, COL3 AS C
) r
```